# If values are equal in dict return the keys python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict of keys and values. I need to compare the values of all the keys if there are the same values in the dict and then return the keys, which have the same values.

```
b = {(1, 1): '4', (2, 1): '4',(3,1):'8',(4,2):'9',(2,4):'10'}
p = dict(zip(b.values(),b.keys()))
```

The output I'm getting:

```
{'4': (2, 1), '8': (3, 1), '9': (4, 2), '10': (2, 4)}
```

Expected output:

```
{(1, 1): '4', (2, 1): '4'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A single liner using `dict comprehension` :

```
>>> {k:v for k, v in b.items() if list(b.values()).count(v) > 1}
```

Here to determine if other values also contain the same, we check for the count to be greater than one.

#driver values :

```
IN : b = {(1, 1): '4', (2, 1): '4',(3,1):'8',(4,2):'9',(2,4):'10'}
OUT : {(1, 1): '4', (2, 1): '4'}
```